# Layered navigation headers showing, but no sub categories or price ranges

Tags: magento, navigation

I'm struggling with an odd one. I see the Layered Navigation headers Category, Price, etc... But no clickable sub options, even though I can see products that fall into each right in front of me.

I have a category called Projectors with two sub categories called Red and Blue. Projectors is an anchor and has no products of its own. Red and Blue have products assigned to them and both categories appear in the drop down navigation at the top.

When navigating to Projectors, you see all of the sub products and the layered navigation headers, but no sub categories or price brackets. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Missing Filter Options]

Rich

Comment: Quick guess: Try refreshing your index from the System menu. It has an entry specifically for layered navigation.

Comment: @clockworkgeek Thanks for the response. I've tried clearing the cache, reindexing, and re-adding the categories. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Please post the content of `template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml` in your theme. Seems the problem is there.

Comment: For some odd reason that only Dropbox could explain, the file was completely empty. Thank you for your help Ivan.

Comment: Ivan, would you post your response as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Dropbox conflict had emptied a number of key template files, including `template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml` as @Ivan Chepurnyi suggested. Serves me right for not using proper source control on this project.